# Test for absolute convergence $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}k^k}{(k+1)^k}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Test for absolute and conditional convergence. $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}k^k}{(k+1)^k}$$

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}|a_n| = \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^k}$$
I'm stuck on what to do next.

Comment: The very first thing to check: Do the terms converge to $0$? If so, the second is: How fast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^k = \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k}$$

What is the limit of $\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k$?

Comment: 1! Since $lim_{k\to\infty}a_k$ is not $0$, then $lim_{k\to\infty}a_k$ diverges?

Comment: That's confusing. Perhaps you mean "Since $\lim_{k\to\infty a_k}\neq 0$ then $\lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^k a_n$ diverges?"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews A *limit* can *diverge*? Now, *I* am confused.

Comment: Well, that was an abuse of terminology - $\sum_{n=1}^k a_n$ diverges, or $\lim \sum_{n=1}^n a_n$ does not exist. Pretty common abuse, however, because we often want to specify which term is changing. Saying $f(i,j)$ diverges as $j\to\infty$ is perhaps more accurate, but saying $\lim_{j\to\infty} f(i,j)$ diverges is common shorthand. @Did